# Double integral of product of Bessel functions in Python

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, bessel-functions, python

I would like to perform a numerical integral (in Python) of the form

$$\displaystyle F_\nu(k) = \int_0^\infty dk' \ k' \int_0^\infty dr\ r \ f(k', r) \ J_\nu(k' r) \ J_\nu(k r),$$

where $J_\nu$ is the $\nu$-th order Bessel function of the first kind.

Moreover, note that the Bessel functions form an orthogonal basis with respect to the weighting factor $r$, i.e.

$$ \int_0^\infty dr \ r \ J_\nu(k'r) \ J_\nu(kr) = \frac{\delta(k' - k)}{k}, \quad k,\ k'>0,$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.

Although this is not impossible by naively performing this integral in Python, it takes a long time to evaluate. However, given the fact that the Bessel functions form an orthogonal basis, and since since this form somewhat resembles a [Hankel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform) (for which packages are available that perform an order of magnitude better than their naive counterparts) I was hoping there might be faster way to evaluate this integral.

Any ideas on how to tackle this integral?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^\infty k' dk' \int_0^\infty r dr f(k',r) J_\nu (k' r) J_\nu (kr)\\
f(k',r) = \int_0^\infty k'' dk'' F_\mu (k',k'') J_\mu (k'' r)\\
\int_0^\infty k' dk' \int_0^\infty r dr \int_0^\infty k'' dk'' F_\mu (k',k'') J_\mu (k'' r) J_\nu (k' r) J_\nu (kr)\\
$$

Where we have substituted $F_\mu(k',k'')$ which is a Hankel transformation of $f(k',r)$

The integral

$$
D((m,\gamma),(m',\gamma'),(m'',\gamma'')) \equiv \int_0^\infty r dr J_m (\gamma r) J_{m'} (\gamma' r) J_{m''} (\gamma '' r)
$$

was studied in [Auluck](https://content.wolfram.com/uploads/sites/19/2013/01/Auluck.pdf) for integer orders.

So assuming I can Fubini the $r$ and $k''$ integrals

$$
\int_0^\infty k' dk' \int_0^\infty k'' dk'' F_\mu (k',k'') \int_0^\infty r dr J_\mu (k'' r) J_\nu (k' r) J_\nu (kr)\\
$$

I'm assuming $\nu$ is an integer now.

$$
\int_0^\infty k' dk' \int_0^\infty k'' dk'' F_\mu (k',k'') D((\mu ,k''),(\nu,k'),(\nu,k))\\
$$

Some examples of $D$ have exact solutions. For example,

$$
D((0,\gamma),(m',\gamma'),(m',\gamma''))
$$

is at the bottom of page 6. But that gets you some expression in Legendre functions and $\frac{k^2+k'^2-k''^2}{2kk'}$, so I don't know how useful that will be.

You could use the approximation on page 24 which gives you an approximation to $D$ as a distribution on $k''$ for smooth weight functions which would hopefully include $F_\mu (k',k'')$. Note however, that formula is not proven there.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time and creative solution. Depending on the accuracy of the approximate semi-empirical representation of the 3B integral this definitely would simplify the problem, as I am quite sure $F_\mu(k', k'')$ would be smooth in my case. For now I opted to use a spline representation of the integrand, which results in an order of magnitude faster (and still accurate) result, which feels like cheating the problem but beggars can't be choosers.